# No display on power up

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, boot-loader, bios

So I have this problem ever since I enabled secure-boot, every time I power up the screen doesn't turn on and it just hang there, I tried to access BIOS many times but no luck, CMOS reset didn't work either

Here what I think happen:

Power on ---> no display----> boot straight to Ubuntu without BIOS

No POST, beeps

Edit: I set Ubuntu as 1st booting option, I had problem with Ubuntu(no display) before this....

This guy had same problem....
But the thing is the video worked for him,
I need to "nomodeset" before boot Ubuntu 
but it boots straight on startup so I'm lost 
[Laptop boots directly to Ubuntu, can't access BIOS or Boot menu anymore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192116/laptop-boots-directly-to-ubuntu-cant-access-bios-or-boot-menu-anymore)

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the o.s. try running [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: I can't ....it halts after power on

Comment: Can you boot into a live CD?

Comment: no I already tried with USB but no luck

Comment: It doesn't even start POST process

Comment: So where does it stop?